# Custom Notification RemoteView dismiss on swipe Left or Right

Tags: android, notifications, dismiss

I used custom audio player notification with custom layout like.

```
simpleContentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
expandedView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.big_notification);
```

and create notification

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("KJV Bible")
            //.setOngoing(false)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDeleteIntent(createOnDismissedIntent(this))
            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID).build();
```

and add listener of custom view

```
public void setListeners(RemoteViews view) {
    Intent previous = new Intent(NOTIFY_PREVIOUS);
    Intent delete = new Intent(NOTIFY_DELETE);
    Intent pause = new Intent(NOTIFY_PAUSE);
    Intent next = new Intent(NOTIFY_NEXT);
    Intent play = new Intent(NOTIFY_PLAY);

    mMyBroadcastReceiver = new NotificationBroadcast(controls);
    IntentFilter filterPrevious = new IntentFilter(NOTIFY_PREVIOUS);
    this.registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver, filterPrevious);

    IntentFilter filterDelete = new IntentFilter(NOTIFY_DELETE);
    this.registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver, filterDelete);

    IntentFilter filterPause = new IntentFilter(NOTIFY_PAUSE);
    this.registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver, filterPause);

    IntentFilter filterNext = new IntentFilter(NOTIFY_NEXT);
    this.registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver, filterNext);

    IntentFilter filterPlay = new IntentFilter(NOTIFY_PLAY);
    this.registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver, filterPlay);

    PendingIntent pPrevious = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, previous, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPrevious, pPrevious);

    PendingIntent pDelete = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, delete, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnDelete, pDelete);

    PendingIntent pPause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, pause, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPause, pPause);

    PendingIntent pNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, next, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnNext, pNext);

    PendingIntent pPlay = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, play, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlay, pPlay);
}
```

Now how can i remove or dismiss this notification swipe left or right when player id pause not on when player in on play mode?

i used setDeleteIntent() but did't work like.

```
private PendingIntent createOnDismissedIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationDismissedReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("notificationId", NOTIFICATION_ID);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, 0);


    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(NOTIFY_DELETE), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: `setOngoing(false)` should do it.

Comment: trying but not working, so comment this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` flag  to dismiss notification in createOnDismissedIntent method.

Updated method below -

```
private PendingIntent createOnDismissedIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationDismissedReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("notificationId", NOTIFICATION_ID);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, 0);


    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(NOTIFY_DELETE), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: can u please explain why PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT?

Comment: i am using custom layout notification in service, that's why this code is not working,b'coz when service is create notification is create as a foreground like this startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
private PendingIntent createOnDismissedIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationDismissedReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("notificationId", NOTIFICATION_ID);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```